# Build when a change is pushed to Bitbucket - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build the changes pushed to Bitbucket. Can I exclude a specific user ?

For example, when user A commits, I don't want Jenkins to trigger the build, but it can be triggered when other users commit changes to the repo.

Comment: You can start the build check the user and then then skip the build.

Comment: How can I do that ?